# Is there a GEDCOM processing tool to determine lineage society eligibility?

Tags: gedcom

It is a lot of work and hard to determine if you have ancestors that have lineage societies (for example, Mayflower, Brewster, Society of the Cincinnati, DAR, ...). There are quite a lot of lineage societies and everyone has quite a few ancestors. Does anyone know of a tool that processes a GEDCOM file and outputs what ancestors potentially match which lineage societies?

Answer (score 8):

It is theoretically possible to build such a tool.
It even seems relatively easy to build such a tool as a service for a large *shared tree* system, where everyone works together to build a single tree; just start at the root of the lineage, mark all descendants and then email all living members.

However, the quality of data in such shared tree systems has been cause for more than one lament, and emailing members that they may qualify for membership in a lineage society followed by a rejection from that lineage society is not likely to increase customer satisfaction.

Surely some lineage societies are already reviewing ancestries sent to them by matching GEDCOM files to their master database, but I am not aware of any publicly available tools. 
Perhaps some societies are working towards the ability to upload your GEDCOM for a quick eligibility check.

Creation of a reasonably accurate tool would require access to the lineage society's master database, or a fair approximation of same.
A tool that checked for eligibility to many lineage societies would require access to just as many databases.

A positive result from such a tool would not guarantee acceptance by the lineage society.
Ultimately, the lineage society itself remains the final arbiter regarding membership eligibility.